# Jmeter CSV File

Tags: jmeter

I have a Long CSV file about 10,000 records in excel to run on jmeter. How can I pick a section of 500 records at a time and run and save the results in a file  and in the next run I select the next 500 records and run the script? Is there any way to do it in jmeter or do I need to update my csv file with the set of records I need to run?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting up a Redis server.
You can load the data on it and then arrange them as a circular queue or  a read-once set.
You can use Jmeter-plugins to access from jmeter.
It can support distributed configurations in a very transparent way.

I takes some work to set it, but definitely worth it.